# Difference between Deferred and Exact background tasks

Tags: android, multithreading, background-task

I was reading [Guide To Background Tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), it's well organized and understandable except a few concepts.
Can anyone differentiate between **Deferred** and **Exact** background Tasks with some realtime android examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deferred tasks**
Every task that is not directly connected to a user interaction and can run at any time in the future can be deferred. The recommended solution for deferred tasks is *WorkManager*.

*WorkManager* makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or the device restarts. See the documentation for *WorkManager* to learn how to schedule these types of tasks.

**Exact tasks**
A task that needs to be executed at an exact point in time can use *AlarmManager.*

To learn more about *AlarmManager*, see Schedule repeating alarms.

Comment: Any example would be more helpful, it seems both works when user is not interacting then where is difference?